# Is there way to write javascript events for pdf render using pdf.js

Tags: javascript, flash, pdf, pdf.js

I have a scenario where I been asked to make online PDF viewer and  on viewing mode the user would select certain area of the PDF and upon selection the marked area boundary w.r.s.t pdf should sent to the server.

example If the User click a area of say created at date the boundary of the selected area should be sent to the server

Now I googled around, and I found that **Pdf.js** can handle the rendering of pdf in browser. Can I, by any chance, associate the event with the PDF pages as I mention above or should I look for some other solution like `flash`

Regards

Answer (score 1):

In the `viewer.js`, there are some listeners like:

- `window.addEventListener('mousedown', function mousedown(evt) {..}`
- `window.addEventListener('mousemove', function keydown(evt) {..}`

You can use those to do the logic of your dragging, selecting, ..

Comment: Molske, would you be able to go into a little more detail on how you would do this?

Comment: @Godrules500 did you get solution for this